# Regex to detect JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Does someone know how to check if a code begins by `<script>` and end by `</script>`. It's just a means to check if code is ok to be inserted in HTML to avoid breaking the site.

So far I've tried to look if `<script>` is there but I need to check both opening and closing.

Any help would be cool :)

Comment: It's the easiest regex to write but it won't check your string is valid. Parse the HTML for that or do additional check.

Comment: Thanks dystroy, I have to admit regex are tricky for me.

Comment: Whoever attempts to answer this question, please take into account that `<script>....</script>.....</script>` is invalid.

Comment: invalid regarding what?

Comment: Aren't you worried that script itself will break the site?

Comment: I have to check, I do not want my users to enter something bad and then layout is broken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this..

```
<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>
```

Comment: Almost correct... except that this doesn't handle double closing tags.

Comment: @JMau: You didn’t surround it with `/`. Also, what is this for?